# Unexpected behavior of upload to SharePoint 2013 via OData if column value uniqueness constraint is violated

Tags: c#, sharepoint, odata

I upload documents to SharePoint 2010 and 2013 with `OData` service `ListData.svc` proxied by Visual Studio-generated service reference. The code for performing this task is similar to C# snippet below:

```
public static void Upload<T>(string libraryName, string localFilePath, string targetLibraryRelativePath, T document)
{
    string fullLibraryPath = ContextFactory.ROOT + LibraryName + targetLibraryRelativePath);
    var ctx = ContextFactory.GetODataContext();
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(localFilePath);
    document.Path = fullLibraryPath ;
    document.Name = fi.Name;
    document.ContentType = "Document";
    var mimeType = DeriveMIMEType(localFilePath);
    using (FileStream sourceFile = System.IO.File.Open(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        ctx.AddObject(libraryName, document);
        ctx.SetSaveStream(document, sourceFile, true, mimeType, fullLibraryPath + "/" + document.Name);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Recently a new business requirement has surfaced: prevent document replicas from getting into the library. The first approach that came to my mind was introducing a new column with mandatory unique value and place there something like MD5 hash:

```
document.MD5 = CalculateMD5Hash(File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile));
```

I expected that if a new upload with the same MD5 hash is attempted the service must prevent the document contents duplicate from reaching the library by virtue of unique hash column value constraint.

My expectations came out only partially correct: while the service throws an exception on such attempt indeed, nevertheless the duplicate contents ends up uploaded, but lacking any attributes of original `document` and hurting this way the integrity of my document library.

While it is not a problem to change implementation a bit and check the document library for equal MD5 hash value existence **prior** to calling `SetSaveStream` this feels like an excessive effort that totally defeats the purpose of declaring the unique constraint for MD5 hash value column.

My question is: am I missing something here and there is some way to make the system perform the fulfillment of document contents uniqueness requirement for me without the penalty of placing inconsistent items to the document library?

Comment: I've recreated your scenario, I get an exception `An error occurred while processing this request.` when I re-upload a file, but I can't see the new entry in the library. Could you give more details about how to end up with the duplicate content being uploaded?

Comment: +1 for the `MD5 hash` idea :)

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: Sure, I create a text column for MD5 requiring unique value in SharePoint2013, put into the snippet above line `document.MD5 = "12345";` before `AddObject` call, create 2 copies of a local file under different names, execute the snippet for each file copy, getting exception on `SaveChanges` call the second time, go to SharePoint UI and observe two lines with 2 files of the same contents. For the second file `MD5` attribute value is `null`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: When you initially tried recreating my scenario you prolly tried uploading the second file with the *same* name. This is not allowed and throws the exception,
that reads the same, but in fact is the different one. You need to enable extended diagnostics in order to see the difference. That's why you didn't see the duplicate uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best alternatives I can think of for the moment are:

1. Checking for the MD5 hash existence in the library before trying to add the document (as you already suggested in the OP):

   ```
   var md5 = GetMd5Hash(File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName));

   // check that the MD5 hash doesn't exist in the library
   if (ctx.Test.Where(i => i.MD5 == md5).Count() == 0)
   {
       try
       {
           document.Path = fullLibraryPath;
           document.Name = fi.Name;
           document.ContentType = "Document";
           var mimeType = DeriveMIMEType(localFilePath);
           using (FileStream sourceFile = System.IO.File.Open(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
           {
               ctx.AddObject(libraryName, document);
               ctx.SetSaveStream(document, sourceFile, true, mimeType, fullLibraryPath + "/" + document.Name);
               ctx.SaveChanges();
           }
       }
       catch (DataServiceRequestException)
       {
           // TODO: log the exception
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using a `try{...}catch{...}` statement in order to catch the exception and delete the added item:

   ```
   using (FileStream sourceFile = System.IO.File.Open(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
       ctx.AddObject(libraryName, document);
       ctx.SetSaveStream(document, sourceFile, true, mimeType, fullLibraryPath + "/" + document.Name);
       try
       {
           ctx.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           _ctx.DeleteObject(document);
           _ctx.SaveChanges();
           // TODO: log the exception
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for offering workaround options. Nevertheless, the original intent of bringing this matter to SO was:
should we accept the weird implementation for given and bother with workarounds, or we just missing some use or setup detail that enforces the following intuitively expected service behavior - "on attempt to upload a document `B` to a library having
value `xyzzy` for uniquely constrained column when the library already has document `A` with the same column value `xyzzy` `B` is not uploaded, exception is thrown instead"?

Comment: Gene, as you already might have noticed, when an item is added, there are actually 2 HTTP requests: a POST and a MERGE; 2 operations are performed, ADD and UPDATE. The trouble in our case is that the first request only contains the document content in it's body. Only in the second request, which actually updates the already created item, the uniqueness constraint can be checked and the exception is thrown. I don't know the reason for it and if it can be changed... Maybe you might want to take a look at some other [APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library)./jj164060.aspx).